# Algorithm for moving a point around an arbitrary non self-crossing closed polygon in N time

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, geometry

I'm looking for an algorithm that would move a point around an arbitrary closed polygon that is not self-crossing in N time. For example, move a point smoothly around a circle in 3 seconds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
1) Calculate the polygon's perimeter  (or estimate it if exact time of circling 
is not critical)
2) divide the perimieter by the time desired for circling
3) move point around polygon at this speed.
```

**Edit** following ire and curses' comment.

Maybe I read the question too literally, I fail to see the difficulty or the points raised by ire_and_curses.

The following describes more specifically the logic I imagine for step #3.  A more exact description would require knowing details about the coordinate system, the structure used to describe the polygon, and indication abou the desired/allowed animation refreshing frequency.

The "travellng point" which goes around the polygon would start *on* any edge of the polygop (maybe on a vertex, as so to make the start and end point more obvious) and would stay on an edge *at all time*.

From this starting point, be it predetermined or randomly selected), the traveling point would move towards towards a vertex, at the calculated speed. Once there it would go towards the other vertex of the edge it just arrived to, and proceed till it returns to the starting point.

The equations for calculating the points on a given edge are the same that for tracing a polygon: simple trig or even pythagoras **(*)**.   The visual effect is based on refreshing the position of the traveling point at least 15 times or so per second.  The refresh frequency (or rather its period) can be used to determine the distance of two consecutive points of the animation.

The only less trivial task is to detect the end of a given edge, i.e. when the traveling point needs to "turn" to follow the next edge.  On these occasions, a fractional travel distance needs to be computed so that the next point in the animation is on the next edge.  Special mention also for extremely short edges, as these may require the fractional distance logic to be repeated (or done differently).

Sorry for such a verbose explanation for a rather straight forward literally ;-) algorithm...

**Correction**: as pointed out by Jefromi in comment for other response, all that is needed with regard to the tracing is merely to decompose the x and y  components of the motion. Although we do need Pythagoras for calculating the distance between each vertex for the perimeter calculation, and we do need to extrapolate because the number of animation steps on an edge is not [necessarily] a integer.

Comment: -1: This is one-dimensional. How do you choose directions? What do you do if you hit an edge? How do you ensure you don't cross your own path?

Comment: How can you cross your path when moving around a polygon "that is *not self-crossing* "? And how do you mean, hit an edge? You're *on* the edges, how can you speak of hitting one?

Comment: @ire_and_cursres: [How do you choose directions?] If you can calculate the perimeter, surely you can handle vectors between points...

Comment: I'm sorry. I read the question differently, and thought it referred to moving a point *within* a polygon. If you are restricted to the perimeter, as you specify, then your solution is fine. I can't tell what the OP intended, but your reading sounds more plausible on reflection. I have retracted my -1, and given you +1 instead. Thanks for taking the time to provide the extra explanation. My apologies again.

Comment: No apologies needed, i&c, these questions are often ambiguous.  In a sense it was a good thing you down rep-ed me a bit, as I find it very unfair that some of these easy questions get rewarded so much, compared with ones that effectively challenge one's knowledge and imagination...

Answer (score 5):

For the record, a circle is not a polygon--it's the limit of a regular polygon as the number of sides go to infinity, but it's not a polygon.  What I'm giving you isn't going to work if you don't have defined points.

Assuming you have your polygon stored in some format like a list of adjacent vertices, do a O(n) check to calculate the perimeter by iterating through them and computing the distance between each point.  Divide that by the time to get the velocity that you should travel.

Now, if you want to compute the path, iterate back through your vertices again and calculate from your current position where your actual position should be on the next timestep, whatever your refresh time step may be (if you need to move down a different edge, calculate how much time it would take to get to the end of your first edge, then continue on from there..).  To travel along the edge, decompose your velocity vector into its components (because you know the slope of the edge from its two endpoints).

Comment: Trigonometry? All the vector math you'll have done here will already be in coordinate form. And if you want to go from point `A = (x_1, y_1)` to point `B = (x_2, y_2)`, in time `T`, travel along the path `c(t) = A + (B-A)*t/T = (x_1 + (x_2-x_1)*t/T, y_1 + (y_2-y_1)*t/T)`.

Comment: Oops, good point!  For some reason I forgot I already had the x/y coordinates and was assuming we just had the angle and total distance.  Editing to fix.

Comment: @DivineWolfwood, I made the same mistake / assumption of about needing trigs or sq roots...  Jefromi is right, although it does get a bit dicey because the number of animation steps to travel a given edge is not always an integer.

Comment: @Jefromi - you should write this as the answer... simple and concise and it's mostly all that is needed (though you should also normalize that paramaterization so all sides are traversed at constant speed).

Comment: @mjv: Yeah, the easiest way is going to be checking to see if you'll overshoot the end of the edge you're traversing: if you would overshoot, instead reduce the length of the time step you're working in by however long it takes to get to the endpoint of the edge and then repeat the process on that next edge.

Answer (score 1):

A little code might answer this with fewer words (though I'm probably too late for any votes here).  Below is Python code that moves a point around a polygon at constant speed.

```
from turtle import *
import numpy as nx
import time

total_time = 10. # time in seconds
step_time = .02 # time for graphics to make each step

# define the polygone by the corner points
#    repeat the start point for a closed polygon
p = nx.array([[0.,0.], [0.,200.], [50.,150.], [200.,200.], [200.,0.], [0.,0.]])

perim = sum([nx.sqrt(sum((p[i]-p[i+1])**2)) for i in range(len(p)-1)])
distance_per_step = (step_time/total_time)*perim

seg_start = p[0]  # segment start point
goto(seg_start[0], seg_start[1])  # start the graphic at this point
for i in range(len(p)-1):
    seg_end = p[i+1]  # final point on the segment
    seg_len = nx.sqrt(sum((seg_start-seg_end)**2))
    n_steps_this_segment = int(seg_len/distance_per_step)
    step = (seg_end-seg_start)/n_steps_this_segment # the vector step
    #
    last_point = seg_start
    for i in range(n_steps_this_segment):
        x = last_point + step
        goto(x[0], x[1])
        last_point = x
        time.sleep(step_time)
    seg_start = seg_end
```

Here I calculated the step size from the step_time (anticipating an graphics delay) but one could calculate the step size, from whatever was needed, for example, the desired speed.